# I am having Error in ASP.Net Mvc Project While applying crud operations with model class

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, model-view-controller, error-handling

Here is my code in Pics
[Controller Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3XNo.png)

[Controller Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VSyJ.png)

[Controller Pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svLNx.png)

[Layout Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7HC9.png)

[Model Class Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhXtG.png)

[database Table data Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWaNk.png)

[Database Table Definition Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l87Ph.png)

[Error Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPZL9.png)

Help me solve This Error .
If you want i can provide you the solution folder.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your tec_cell from database can't be cast to Int32 in you model class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Actuall reason wa typing mistake or dr[].